# Multiple modifications of state inside one Vuex mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a question regarding style, or rather: best practices.

I have a simple `notification` Vuex module, where the state consists of a `notifications` array and a `maxId` integer.

I have two mutations, one for adding a notification to the array and another for removing one.

I'd like to bump `maxId` every time I a new notification is added.

It seems to me like the right way of doing this is with two mutations, so that each mutation only does one thing, and then commit both mutations from the "add notification" action.

Something like this:

```js
[ADD_NOTIFICATION] (state, notification) {
  state.notifications.push(notification)
}

[BUMP_MAX_ID] (state) {
  state.maxId += 1
}
```

However, since these two are so tightly coupled, is there any good argument for keeping them separate? Couldn't I just add `state.maxId += 1` in the first mutation as a second expression? I think that one could say in this case having just one mutation might end up being the simpler solution.

I know both ways work, I'm just curious what's your take.

Comment: you do not need `maxId`. you can create a getter which gets you total notification count

Comment: @NileshPatel, since notifications are also going to be removed, I was worried a count might not be the best option and could raise concurrency issues with duplicate `id`s. Maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: concurrency issue you may have with `maxId` as well. using `uuid` would be better option to avoid any duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If your maxId should be bumped whenever a notification is added, you **MUST** keep the two assignments on the same mutation so there's no chance of someone committing `ADD_NOTIFICATION` without bumping the id.

The only reason to keep `BUMP_MAX_ID` as an exposed mutation type would be if you need to bump your id without doing anything else to the store. If you don't need to do that, exposing it can create some unnecessary bugs.

So, the final code would look like as you proposed in your question.

```js
const mutations = {
  [ADD_NOTIFICATION] (state, notification) {
    state.notifications.push(notification);
    state.maxId += 1
  },
  // [BUMP_MAX_ID] removed
}
```

Also, if you have to bump your maxId every time any other mutations are commited, you need to write that on every mutation too, like this

```js
const mutations = {
  [MUTATION_1] (state, payload) {
    doSomething(state);
    state.maxId += 1;
  },
  [MUTATION_2] (state, payload) {
    doSomethingElse(state);
    state.maxId += 1;
  },
  // and so on...
};
```

If you REALLY don't want to write `state.maxId` += 1 every time, you can create a helper function

```js
function applyIdBumper(state, mutate) {
  mutate(state);
  state.maxId += 1;
}
```